# e-mails getting sent automatically every morning

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I have a form I built for a client, it takes in user information and send it to my client and I. It has input validation and will not allow a user to send an e-mail without filling out the form.

What I cannot figure out is how the form is getting sent to me every morning for the last 3 days in a row and 5 emails are send at exactly 7:48am. The weirdest part about it is that the form is blank.

Also note: The form is working correctly every time from multiple different devices and browsers when testing it.

I am using PHP to send the form, javascript for form validation, HTML and CSS. Below is the relevant code (to reduce the code I left out the most of the inputs, I kept only one field so you can see how everything is working)

HTML

```
<form method="post" name="form" id="email-form" action="css/form-to-email.php">

    <p class="blue" id="body-text-name">Name: <input id="input-name" name="fname" type="text" required />

    <input class="btn" onClick="return IsEmpty()" type="submit" name='submit' />

</form>
```

javascript

```
function IsEmpty() {
   if (document.forms['form'].name.value == "") {
        alert("empty");
       return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

and PHP

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}

$fname = $_POST['fname'];


$to = 'someEmail@some.com';
$cc = '';
$recipients = $to.", ".$cc;


$email_subject = "Order Form";
$email_body = "Order For: $fname\n\n";


$headers = "From: Order_Form\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: \r\n";

mail($recipients,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header('Location: ../index1.html');

?>
```

I have searched and searched for an answer but I cannot figure out for the life of me what is causing this or were to look. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would check what this is actually doing! I dont think its what you think. `document.forms['form'].name.value` Fix that and maybe the crawlers wont be able to cause the form to run. Try this `document.getElementById('input-name').value` instead

Comment: @blex that sounds like a very possible solution. However I am not sure what you mean by parameter checking. Could you either show me some code or give me a link to where I can find it and read up on it?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Just do `echo "error; you need to submit the form!"; exit();` to exit the script if `$_POST['submit']` is not set. Because with the code you posted, if you typed the URL of the script directly in your browser address bar, you would get the error message, but the email would still be sent.

Comment: @RiggsFolly That also seems like a possibility, is there a Syntax error, I am fairly new to javascript so, it might be that part. How can I check it?

Comment: Change the code and TEST IT. Alternatively use the browser debugger and see if there is such a thing as `document.forms['form'].name.value`

Comment: @RiggsFolly The only way I can test it is to wait till 7:48am tomorrow morning correct?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith No, to test it, you just need to go to `yoursite.com/path/to/css/form-to-email.php` and then look in your inbox (there should be nothing).

Comment: @blex oh goctha, I will check now.

Comment: @blex You nailed it! I got this error `error; you need to submit the form!` on the page and it sent me a blank email. So ecarrizo answer below is going to fix the issue! Thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be possible that something (an user, a bot) is visiting your css/form-to-email.php directly.

So, When you visit css/form-to-email.php directly

In the "If" block you are echoing a message but not preventing that the script continue it execution, so the other code after that block runs always.

`echo "error; you need to submit the form!";`

should be:

```
return  echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
```

or

```
 echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
 exit(); // || die() its the same.
```

You also could throw an exception.

```
throw new Exception("error; you need to submit the form!");
```

Comment: This sounds very promising, I will update my code with this. But to bad I won't know for sure whether or not it work until tomorrow morning at 7:48am :/

Comment: You could try it by your self just accessing manually css/form-to-email.php in the browser, try it without return, it should send an email, try it with the return or exit, it should not send the email.

Comment: Yeah, read my last comment under my original question to blex. You two just helped me out a ton, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
function IsEmpty() {
   if (document.forms['form'].name.value == "") {
        alert("empty");
       return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

Is wrong!

```
document.forms['form'].name.value
```

returns the value of the name field of the form tag i.e. in your case from this HTML it returns 'form' **and will always be set to that**

```
<form method="post" name="form" id="email-form" action="css/form-to-email.php">
```

from the `name="form"` property.

Change the script to get the content of the field you actually want to check!!

```
function IsEmpty() {
   if (document.getElementById('input-name').value == "") {
        alert("empty");
       return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

Also this validation should be done in the PHP script that accepts this data and generates the email.

```
<?php
if( ! isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
    exit;
}

if ( ! isset($_POST['fname'] ) {
    echo "error; You must have something in this field!";
    exit;
}

$fname = $_POST['fname'];

$to = 'someEmail@some.com';
$cc = '';
$recipients = $to.", ".$cc;

$email_subject = "Order Form";
$email_body = "Order For: $fname\n\n";

$headers = "From: Order_Form\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: \r\n";

mail($recipients,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header('Location: ../index1.html');

?>
```

Comment: I marked your answer up, for helping me with this error. However, the issue ended up being the answer ecarrizo put up. But Thank You! For your time on correcting that part of the form for me!

Comment: This was your issue. You were testing a field for the existance of data, **that would always contain data** and **not** the actual field that you were interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The could be using the raw URL to send the email, most likely web crawlers since you mention the time consistency. Best to have  validation on the server side as well, that should stop it.